# How do I align an input with the top of multi-line text?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a checkbox with the top of some multi-line text that has a custom line height.

I've been messing with `inline-grid` but I can't think of a nice way to do this without having fixed margin offsets.

Here's my current approach:

```css
.checkbox {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  line-height: 2;
}
  
 .checkbox input {
   margin-right: 10px; 
 }
```

```html
<div style="max-width: 200px">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>
        Here is some text that wraps over multiple lines.
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone have any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
label { line-height: 2; }

label:first-line { line-height: 1; }
```

```css
.checkbox {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  
}
  
.checkbox input {
  margin-right: 10px; 
}

label{
  line-height: 2;
}

label:first-line {
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width: 200px">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>
      Here is some text that wraps over multiple lines.
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's almost there but `absolute` position takes it out of the flow so elements below would overlap I think.

Comment: Bam! Nice one! 

TIL `:first-line`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **margin-top:10px;** in **.checkbox input** css.

```css
.checkbox {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  line-height: 2;
}
  
 .checkbox input {
   margin-right: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px; 
 }
```

```html
<div style="max-width: 200px">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>
        Here is some text that wraps over multiple lines.
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>
        Here is some text that wraps over multiple lines.
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid using any fixed px margin offsets if I could get away with it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @dannymidnight Ohh yeah. I didn't see you don't want to use margin offsets. Never mind.